# Discord automessaging script

Tags: discord.js

I want to code a script which increases by 1 at the end of each message output. But I don't know how can I do that. Example:
stackoverflow 1
stackoverflow 2
stackoverflow 3

Need help.

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Which part are you stuck on?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a simple `for-loop`. You could try something like this:

```js
const loopCount = 10
for(i = 0; i < loopCount; i++) {
  message.channel.send(`Test number ${i + 1}`);
}
```

The output would be:

```
Test number 1
Test number 2
Test number 3
Test number 4
Test number 5
Test number 6
Test number 7
Test number 8
Test number 9
Test number 10
```

Comment: @Erdin Did this fix your problem?